# When/Where/how did "sorrowing" become a verb?

Tags: etymology

What is the 
etymology or history of the verb "sorrowing"? My 1993 edition of The New Shorter OED doesn't have a year and says "it is the act of..."

Comment: [sorrowing](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/sorrowing) is an adjective  and it's listed as an [adjective](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/sorrowing) by TFD too

Comment: "Sorrow", in the sense of causing sorrow, can be a verb.  Adding "-ing" to it is perfectly legit.

Comment: @HotLicks *Sorrowing* refers to experiencing or displaying sorrow, not causing it.

Comment: @MishaR - It sorrows me to hear that.

Comment: @HotLicks Come on don't be sorrowin a brother like that.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Online Etymology Dictionary entry](https://www.etymonline.com/word/sorrow) - Old English *sorgian*, from the noun form *sorg*. The entry for the noun goes back further, possibly to Proto-Indo-European.